# Implement a LZ78 algorithm in Java

Tags: java, encoding, dictionary, decoding

I have to implement the encoder and decoder of LZ78 to make a .txt compressed and after that, make a .txt decompressed

For that I already made the encoder, the text output is coded as follows:

```
Text: "I have to improve my english"
Coded: "0I0 0h0a0v0e2t0o2i0m0p0r..."
```

LZ78 works with a dictionary, the numbers in the string means the index of the long dictionary entry, 0 if the letter isn't in the dictionary.

The problem is: if the text string is a number chain, how can I differentiate the numbers of the index with the numbers of the text string?

```
Text: "56786263...1234" <- the last entry can be ((index 12 concat'3')concat index 4) instead of (index 123 concat '4')
Coded: "050607082223...'randomnumber'4"
Dictionary: (List<String>)
...
123: 'randomnumber' <- this is saved as a string
...
```

There would be no problem if the dictionary does not have more than 9 entries.
I can't use separators, because that will add a lot of data in the coded text.
I have to use bufferedReader to get data from the coded text.
If something is not clear, i will put some extra information.

```
    BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(codedText));
    BufferedWriter bufW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(decodedText));

    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int i=0;
    int aux=bufR.read();
    while(aux!=-1) {
        list.add((char)aux);
        i++;
        aux=bufR.read();
    }

    System.out.println(list);
```

With that, I have in "list" the char sequence that I compressed with other method.
But the problem is how to group the pairs "number/letter" if the letter is a number, without any type of writable separator.

Add full code

```
    public class LZ78 {

List<String> diccionario;

public LZ78() {
    diccionario = new ArrayList<String>();
    diccionario.add(null);
}



public List<Character> codificar(List<Integer> listaNumeros){
    String codif="";
    List<Character> listaC =new ArrayList<Character>();
    String letra="";
    boolean brea=false;
    int posicion=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=listaNumeros.size()+1;i++){
        int num=listaNumeros.get(i);
        letra+=(char)num;

        if(!diccionario.contains(letra)){   
            diccionario.add(letra);
            codif+=0;
            listaC.add('0');
            codif+=letra;
            char paso=letra.charAt(0);
            listaC.add(paso);
            letra="";

        }else{

            while(diccionario.contains(letra)){

                i++;

                if(i>=listaNumeros.size()){

                    brea=true;


                    if(!diccionario.contains(letra)){
                    listaC.add('0');
                    char paso2=letra.charAt(0);
                    listaC.add(paso2);
                    }else{
                        int index=diccionario.indexOf(letra);
                        String paso3=""+index;
                        for (int j = 0; j < paso3.length(); j++) {
                            listaC.add(paso3.charAt(j));
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("BREAK!");
                    break;
                }
                posicion=diccionario.indexOf(letra);
                num=listaNumeros.get(i);
                letra+=(char)num;


            }

            if(brea){
                break;
            }

            i++;

            diccionario.add(letra);
            letra=""+letra.charAt(letra.length()-1);    
            codif+=posicion;

            String numero=""+posicion;
            for (int j = 0; j < numero.length(); j++) {
                listaC.add(numero.charAt(j));
            }


            codif+=letra;   
            char paso=letra.charAt(0);
            listaC.add(paso);

            letra="";
            i--;

        }
    }

    System.out.println(codif);

    return listaC;
}



//public void decodificar(List<Integer>)


public void codificacion(File textoPlano, File textoPlanoCodificado)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufLectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            textoPlano));
    BufferedWriter bufEscritura = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            textoPlanoCodificado));

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i=0;
    int cosa=bufLectura.read();
    while(cosa!=-1) {
        list.add(cosa);
        i++;
        cosa=bufLectura.read();
    }

    List<Character> code=codificar(list);

    char[] codigo=new char[code.size()];

    for (int j = 0; j < code.size(); j++) {
        //System.out.print(j+":'"+code.get(j)+"'   ");
        codigo[j]=code.get(j);

        bufEscritura.write(codigo[j]);
    }


    System.out.println("FIN codificacion");


    bufEscritura.close();

}

public void decodificacion(File textoC, File textoD) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufLectura = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textoC));
    BufferedWriter bufEscritura = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textoD));

    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int i=0;
    int cosa=bufLectura.read();
    while(cosa!=-1) {
        list.add((char)cosa);
        i++;
        cosa=bufLectura.read();
    }

    System.out.println(list);

    //List<Integer> list2 =decodificar(list);
    /*
    List<Character> code=codificar(list);

    char[] codigo=new char[code.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < code.size()-1; j++) {
        codigo[j]=code.get(j);

        bufEscritura.write(codigo[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("FIN codificacion");


    bufEscritura.close();
    */
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LZ78 lz78 = new LZ78();
    File textoPlano, textoPlanoCodificado, textoPlanoDecodificado;

    textoPlano = new File("C:/pruebas/T.txt");
    textoPlanoCodificado = new File("C:/pruebas/TOut.txt");
    textoPlanoDecodificado = new File("C:/pruebas/TDecOut.txt");
    lz78.codificacion(textoPlano, textoPlanoCodificado);
    lz78.decodificacion(textoPlanoCodificado, textoPlanoDecodificado);

    /*
     * textoPlano = new File("C:/pruebas/MobyDick.txt");
     * textoPlanoCodificado = new File("C:/pruebas/MobyDickOut.txt");
     * textoPlanoDecodificado = new File("C:/pruebas/MobyDickDecOut.txt");
     * lz78.codificacion(textoPlano, textoPlanoCodificado);
     * lz78.decodificacion(textoPlanoCodificado, textoPlanoDecodificado);
     * 
     * textoPlano = new File("C:/pruebas/Quixote.txt"); textoPlanoCodificado
     * = new File("C:/pruebas/QuixoteOut.txt"); textoPlanoDecodificado = new
     * File("C:/pruebas/QuixoteDecOut.txt"); lz78.codificacion(textoPlano,
     * textoPlanoCodificado); lz78.decodificacion(textoPlanoCodificado,
     * textoPlanoDecodificado);
     */
}
```

}

Comment: An "entry" should really be a fixed-format record. E.g. 2 bytes for the dictionary index (`i`), 2 bytes for the length of the string (`n`), then following `n` bytes are the string. I'm not sure your output should be a String, or that a Reader should be used or input - compression algorithms usually work with binary data, not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I am assuming this is homework. If it's not, then you should be operating on bits (not characters) and implementing [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) instead of [LZ78](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78)*

The length of the dictionary index depends on the total size of your dictionary. While there are only 9 entries, you can just use 1 character. As soon as there are 10 entries in your dictionary, you need to use 2 characters for the index for all your entries.

Note that the decoder will know how many dictionary entries it has seen when it processes the stream, so you do not need to store the size of the dictionary separately and can just gradually increase the number of characters you use to store the index. *I.e. as soon as you store your 10th dictionary entry, you start using 2 characters for all future indexes. After making the 100th dictionary entry, you use 3 characters and so on.*

Edit: [This link](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/curious/compression/lzw.html#decompression) has an example step-by-step that shows the dictionary being rebuilt in the decoding phase. Although the link describes LZW (not LZ78), the idea is the same: You need to rebuild the whole dictionary while decoding, and cannot reuse the dictionary from the encoding step (e.g. think about the case where decoder and encoder could be on separate computers -> the dictionary is *not* sent across the network.)

Comment: You cannot assume that the dictionary is known to both the encoder and decoder. Instead, you should build the dictionary every time you encode and every time you decode. If you do that, you don't need a separator, as the length of your index will always be diccionario.size()

Comment: So to clarify: You currently do create your dictionary while encoding, so that's okay. However, you need to recreate the dictionary the same way when you decode. At the beginning of `codificacion` the dictionary `diccionario` should be empty and at the beginning of `decodificacion` the dictionary should be empty. Then as you can see, the length of the number `code.size()` should always be `diccionario.size()`. See the link I added for more info.

Comment: "the case where decoder and encoder could be on separate computers"
This is the problem's context. But the real problem is not to decode, but make a dictionary from the text buffer to make the message and implement some way to not confuse index numbers with character numbers
For example:
...
dictionary entry 10="456"
...
dictionary entry 100="jfas"
...
There are 123 dictionary entries(example)
text to decode= "..0a1001004..."
Right now, I have two possibilities:
-Read index 10 and add character '0'
-Read index 100 and add character '1'
-I can't read 1001 because the size
How can I diff. that?

Comment: You read as many characters as the *current* size of the dictionary. So in your example, the dictionary has size 123 so you read index 100. But the key point is that **at the beginning of the encode/decode, your dictionary should have size 0.** Then in the middle of the text maybe the dictionary has size 14 as you added 14 elements: So you always read 2 chars as the index. You do this until your dictionary has size 99, afterwards you always read 3 chars as the index. You don't need a separator.

Comment: I implemented what you said, but the encoded text is larger than the original. Anyway thanks for helping. If I find a solution I'll post here

Comment: This is really the way to do it. Try your code on some really long text (e.g. one of the public domain ebooks [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/)), it should get smaller eventually. The other two improvements you could do are [packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch#Packing_order) or using a common starting-dictionary with all 26 letters of the alphabet as in [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch#Example). Also, you might want to look at the definition of [prefix-free codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) to understand more.